# How can I avoid clipping my xticks?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting some data that has an associated date.  However, the far most right xtick (Apr 2017) is clipped because the xtick is too long.

Besides rotating or reformatting the tick, how can I avoiid this sort of clipping?

[image]

Comment: Think there is an hjust parameter for that in theme

Comment: Maybe see [plot.margin](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/theme.html)

Comment: Any feedback for me?

Comment: @MikeWise just accepted the answer, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hjust` paramters in `theme(axis.text=` does what you need:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
s <- c(320,790,810,820,780,780,680,700,600,380,420,620,310)
d <- seq(ymd('2016-03-01'),ymd('2017-03-01'), by = '1 month')
df <- data.frame(Date=d,No.Sales=s)

ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(Date,No.Sales),stat="identity") + 
             theme_bw() + 
             labs(title="Condo Sales",
                  subtitle="Montly counts of condo sales in Toronto") +
             theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
                   axis.text=element_text( hjust=1) )
```

Yielding:

[image]